# optimizing query - condition as the result of complex query

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have a code like below. The condition in where clause is the result of quite complex query with a lot of conditions and searching min and max values which takes too leng to process. Is there a way how to optimize it? Thank you in advance.

```html
SELECT *
    FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test a
   WHERE dwh_insert_process =
         (SELECT MAX(dwh_insert_process) dwh_insert_process
            FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test b
           WHERE b.id_obchodu = a.id_obchodu
             AND b.id_obchodu_poradi = a.id_obchodu_poradi
             )
     AND (datum_obchodu >= to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') OR
         ((datum_obchodu < to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) AND
         ((SELECT MIN(c.insert_sysdate) insert_sysdate
               FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test c
              WHERE c.id_obchodu = a.id_obchodu
                AND c.id_obchodu_poradi = a.id_obchodu_poradi)) >=to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
                 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be rewritten with analytic functions like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT a.*,
               MAX(dwh_insert_process) OVER (PARTITION BY id_obchodu, id_obchodu_poradi) max_dwh_insert_process,
               MIN(insert_sysdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id_obchodu, id_obchodu_poradi) min_insert_sysdate
        FROM   middle_offic.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test a)
WHERE  dwh_insert_process = max_dwh_insert_process
AND    (datatum_obchodu >= to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
        OR
        (datatum_obchodu < to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
         AND min_insert_sysdate >= to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')));
```

You'd have to test to make sure this query returns the same results as your current query, but it should be a bit more performant as it's only querying the table once, plus the min/max is being done in one fell swoop, rather than once for each key (in your case, for each id_obchodu and id_obchodu_poradi pair).

Comment: thank you, all solutions to my question are efficient, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you see it this works and gives you better performances?  I tried to do only one SELECT using middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test in the WHERE condition, but I am not sure about perform.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_obchodu,id_obchodu_poradi,MAX(dwh_insert_process) dwh_insert_process, MIN(c.insert_sysdate) insert_sysdate
           FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test
           GROUP BY id_obchodu,id_obchodu_poradi) D ON D.id_obchodu = a.id_obchodu AND D.id_obchodu_poradi = a.id_obchodu_poradi
WHERE a.dwh_insert_process = D.dwh_insert_process
    AND (a.datum_obchodu >= to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
         OR ((datum_obchodu < to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))  
             AND D.insert_sysdate >=to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
             )
        )
```

Comment: thank you, all solutions to my question are efficient, thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this to make use of joins

```
SELECT  *
FROM    middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_obchodu,id_obchodu_poradi, MAX(dwh_insert_process) dwh_insert_process, MIN(c.insert_sysdate) insert_sysdate
            FROM middle_office.f_d_obchody_zmeny_test b
            GROUP BY id_obchodu,id_obchodu_poradi) b
           ON b.id_obchodu = a.id_obchodu
             AND b.id_obchodu_poradi = a.id_obchodu_poradi
             AND a.dwh_insert_process = b.dwh_insert_process
WHERE (datum_obchodu >= to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') OR
     (datum_obchodu < to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND b.insert_sysdate >=to_date('01.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')))
```

Comment: thank you, all solutions to my question are efficient, thank you